# Error loading @capacitor/ios package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@capacitor/ios/package'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6

I am new to the Ionic Framework while running command **ionic info** its showing following warning.
My inoic application version is as:

ionic info:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.4 (/usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.3.8
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 15.0.1
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 15.0.1
   @angular/cli                  : 15.0.1
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 4.5.0
   @capacitor/android : not installed
   @capacitor/core    : 4.5.0
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : 1.7.1

System:

   NodeJS : v14.21.1 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.17
   OS     : Linux 5.14
```

[WARN] Error loading @capacitor/ios package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@capacitor/ios/package'

```
   Require stack:
   - /usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/project/index.js
   - /usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/index.js
   - /usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/index.js
   - /usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/bin/ionic
```

[WARN] Error loading @capacitor/android package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@capacitor/android/package'

```
   Require stack:
   - /usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/project/index.js
   - /usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/index.js
   - /usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/index.js
   - /usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/bin/ionic
```

Please suggest how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running following commands fix the issue:

```
npm install @capacitor/ios
npm install @capacitor/android
```